# Exclude a Wordpress category by name from a blog

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a WP blog with a list of categories. I have specific template which is applied to a category called "News" which is all fine and working, but now I need to make sure that the posts in this category are not included in the main blog. I've tried a few bits and it hasn't worked out for me. Anyone any suggestions?

As I'm working off a dev/test/prod environment which were all set up by different people (... le sigh...) the same categories all have different id's so I was hoping to do it off the category name.

Cheers,

T

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for that Giannis. I knew I could do it with the query_posts negative category type. Thanks for putting me on the right track though.

I have to work this off the category name, that's the only provision of this query. So to do this, I got the category id from the name:

```
$exclude = get_cat_ID('News');
$q = 'cat=-'.$exclude;
query_posts($q);
```

Put this at the top of the loop.php and solved my problem.

Thanks again everyone, love Stackoverflow!

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about where you inserted this code in loop.php? Maybe show some of the surrounding code?

Comment: It goes before the loop. It's used to define the query.

Answer (score 2):

Excluding a category from the loop is quite simple, you just need to pass the category ID as a parameter, for example to exclude categories with id 3 and 8:

```
<?php query_posts('cat=-3,-8'); ?>
```

In your case, it is not possible to exclude a category by its name (category_name parameter).

You can also try using a plugin if that's easier for the multiple environment situation:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simply-exclude/

Answer (score 2):

I did it completely differenly, and using slugs only, as such:

```
$featured_args = array(
    'post_type' => 'news', // I have a custom post type, 'news'
    'tax_query' => array (
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'subject', // I have a custom taxonomy, 'subject'
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array('politics', 'economy-and-business', 'disasters'), 
            'operator' => 'NOT IN' // This operator ensures that the values listed in 'term' are excluded
        )
    ),
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

$featured_query = new WP_Query($featured_args);
```

Note that there exists an array entry, called **tax_query**, which also containts another array that containts a parameters called **operator**, and this **operator** has a value of **NOT IN**, which will exclude the values in the **term** field as opposed to including them.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** Please be advised that if a post has two taxonomy terms, and one of those terms is in the list of terms to exclude, then this will not be part of the result.

For more details, read here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thanks for the input @Greeso! Always good to get feedback on 3D object array contents! To be honest, this suits a larger, more complex organism. The solution I used was small and suited my very limited need. I knew the exact content of the site so it was easier to work with. But thanks for this, might help someone with a larger scale need!